# Instaloader error while fetching csrftoken

Tags: python, instaloader

Im trying to get the list of the followers in my instagram account.
I see that the program succeeds to log in because every time I run it I receive an email from instagram about a new access to my instagram account but then I get this error.
About 2 week ago everything worked fine and i was able to get the list.

This is the error I get:

```
    L.login(username, password)  # (login)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/instaloader/instaloader.py", line 634, in login
    self.context.login(user, passwd)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/instaloader/instaloadercontext.py", line 265, in login
    session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': login.cookies['csrftoken']})
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 335, in __getitem__
    return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 414, in _find_no_duplicates
    raise KeyError(f"name={name!r}, domain={domain!r}, path={path!r}")
KeyError: "name='csrftoken', domain=None, path=None"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like something changed on the Instagram side and this is now a known issue. It can be found on the instaloader issue tracker:

https://github.com/instaloader/instaloader/issues/1758

There seem to be some workarounds listed in the issue. You can try them or wait for the maintainer to accept a patch/update to fix the issue.

In the future, try to check the project's bug tracking system first to see if what you're experience is a known issue. That way, you can work with other developers to work together and test out solutions to the problem.